# Can I add if-else condition in widget using flutter

Tags: flutter

```
body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Class: ${className}',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.grey[700],
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 10),
                Text(
                  'Date: ${date}',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.grey[700],
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 10),
                Text(
                  'Subject: ${subjectName}',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.grey[700],
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 50),
                Text(
                  '${homeWorkTitle}',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.grey[700],
                    fontSize: 15,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 15),
                GestureDetector(
                  child: SizedBox(
                      height: 50,
                      width: 150,
                      child: Link(
                        uri: Uri.parse("http://bolpur.tigps.theretreathotels.in/assets/hw_teacher_upload/${homeWorkFileName}"),
                        builder: (context,followlink) {
                          return ElevatedButton(
                              onPressed: followlink,
                              child: const Text('Download PDF')
                          );
                        },
                      )),
                ),

# HERE I want add if condition /////////****

                const SizedBox(height: 50),
                Text(
                  'Upload your task',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.grey[700],
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 10),
                GestureDetector(
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 50,
                    width: 150,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: openFiles,
                      child: const Text("Upload PDF"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 10),
                if (_filePath != null)
                  Text('File Path: $_filePath')
                else
                  const Text('No file selected'),
                const SizedBox(height: 150),
                GestureDetector(
                  child: Center(
                    child: Container(
                      height: 60,
                      width: 600,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100)),
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.teal, // background color
                          foregroundColor: Colors.white, // text color
                        ),
                        onPressed: () async {
                          setState(() => isLoading = true);
                          await uploadImage();
                          setState(() => isLoading = false);
                        },
                        child: Center(
                          child: isLoading ? const Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Text('Loading...', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                              SizedBox(width: 10,),
                              CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.white,),
                            ],
                          ) : const Text( "Submit", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20,),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )),
# HERE I want add if condition /////////****
```

in the above code I add

```
if (condition) {}
```

but I got errors.

Comment: You have to be more specific and format your question better. You already have an `if` in there `if (_filePath != null)`. It works just like that. "I got errors" is also not very useful for us. What errors? What have you tried? Please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

I think you should re-format your question to be better looking and more informative, but in general you're probably looking for the Conditional (ternary) operator

for example:

```
...
child: isConditionSatisfied ?
    const SuccessView() : const WaitingView()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your problem fully but I'll try to give a more general answer. if-conditions inside the list of children in a Column are a special kind of so called *collection if*. Read more about it [here](https://dart.dev/language/collections#control-flow-operators). In any case, these never use curly braces for the body of the if so `if (condition){}` is not possible. However, if you want to group some widgets under a single condition you can make use of the spread operator `...`. It can be used like this:

```
Column(
  children: [
    Container(),
    Container(),
    if (condition) ... [
      Container(),
      Container(),
      Container(),
    ],
    Container()
  ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the ternary operator like the following

```
 Container(
   child: condition == true? Text(): Icon()
     )
```

if you have more conditions than 2 a number with 3 possible numbers for example you can use it like this

```
Container(
  child: number == 1? Text(): number==2? Icon() : IconButton()
   )
```

Comment: If the situation has a lot of cases, a function maybe better choice. Cause it’s easy to read and convenient to evolve into a strategy design pattern.

Answer (score -1):

Absolutely, you can incorporate if-else conditions within Flutter widgets. Flutter offers a declarative way of building UI through its widget system, allowing you to conditionally render different UI components based on certain conditions.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  bool condition = true; // Your condition here

  return MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: condition
            ? Text('Condition is true')
            : Text('Condition is false'),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

In this case, the condition variable determines which Text widget gets displayed based on its value. If condition is true, it displays 'Condition is true', otherwise, it displays 'Condition is false'.

You can use if-else conditions not only to switch between widgets but also to determine their properties or configurations:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  bool loggedIn = true; // Example login condition
  IconData icon = loggedIn ? Icons.check : Icons.error; // Using ternary operator to set different icons
  
  return MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Conditional Widgets'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          if (loggedIn)
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(icon),
              onPressed: () {
                // Some action
              },
            ),
          else
            Text('Not logged in'),
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: loggedIn ? Text('Welcome!') : Text('Please login'),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Here, the app bar changes its actions based on whether the user is logged in or not. If logged in, it shows an icon button with a check mark icon; otherwise, it displays a text indicating 'Not logged in'. The body of the scaffold also changes its content based on the login status.

Using if-else conditions in Flutter widgets is quite flexible and allows you to dynamically adjust the UI based on changing conditions within your app.